# Spring mvc:resources tag understanding

Tags: java, xml, spring

In Spring Petclinic the following tag is used for static content .

```
"<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/> "
```

But I am facing problems in understanding this because the mapping and the location are same . So what purpose will this tag solve ?If the css file request is like.

"spring:url value="/resources/css/petclinic.css" var="petclinicCss" "

then what would be the converted URL after mvc:resources tag has been executed .

Answer (score 3):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Any requests from this url pattern `/resources/**` , Spring will look for `/resources/`

1. `mapping` is url pattern
2. `location` where the resources exists in project class-path

[Configuring Serving of Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

---

Example usages,

1. By using JSTL `<c:url>`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.js" />"></script>
   ```
2. By using [`<spring:url>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.url)

   ```
   <spring:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" var="favicon" />
   ```

Comment: A Nyar Thar : Thanks for the reply . I have one query . If <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.js" />"></script> is executed . Then where will spring look for the Jquery.js file . My understanding is the it will look inside /resources and the remaining path will remain same . Hence it will find the js file at this location /resources/js/jquery.js . But what value add has been done by mvc:resources tag here .

Comment: @Anshul The actual url in page loading will be `<context-path>/resources/js/jquery.js` ..

Answer (score 0):

As sayed, the "location" is where your files are and "pattern" the URL used to call them.

You will understand with this exemple. Suppose we have this WebContent folders structure :

```
-WebContent
    -META-INF
    -WEB-INF
        -assets
            -css
                *myview.css
            -js
        -view
            *myview.jsp //or html or any kind of view format)
```

now, in spring dispatcher I use the tag like this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />
```

then, in my "myview.jsp" to call "myview.css" i have to write this :

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/myview.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In fact, what Spring dispatcher do is for all url starting with "/reources/", expressed by [mapping="/resources/**] (start with "resources" and ** means no matter the end) it replace the "/resources/" by "/WEB-INF/assets/" (configured by location="/WEB-INF/assets/") and append the rest of the url to "/WEB-INF/assets/" to fin the location of the resources in the project structure.

I hope it was clear now